# How to update external properties from database table using UI?

Tags: java, properties

In my Spring Boot application I have a file `values.properties` with some values that is used in my app, for example:

```
value.added.tax=16
non.taxed.minimum=1300
```

and so on. Then I have a class fields:

```
private static final Integer VAT = readProp("value.added.tax");
private static final Integer NTM = readProp("non.taxed.minimum");
```

In `readProp()` method these properties are read with `InputStream`. Finally I have public getters `getVat()` and `getNtm()` that all my rest code used.

All these values are considered to be constants, however sometimes they could be changed (about once per year). For this purpose I want to add database table with corresponding values and administrator's UI console, where all the values could be updated. Then I plan to update my `values.properties` file with values from table with the similar `writeProp()` method with `OutputStream`.

The reason why I don't read values directly from a database table in my code is that they are using very often in many functions and the values will be change very rarely (about once a year).

Is this a good practice to have such table and update external properties file from it?

In order to implement that I have to set all the fields as **non-final** and add a setters to have the possibility to update them, am I right?

Help me please, many thanks.

Comment: If the value can change, even rarely, then it's not constant. It seems redundant to have the values in a properties file and in the database.  Why not read from the database, but provide a mechanism to trigger reading from the database again when needed?  (Be careful synchronizing the values.)

Comment: I agree, it should not be constant if it may change, even rarely. In this case reading from properties file is just like a buffer (because reading from db is much more expensive). And I'd update the properties file in the transaction when user updates the value in DB, in that case values always will be fresh and synchronized. That was my idea.